# WPF Tabcontrol Same kind of template for all Tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, tabcontrol

Iam working around with WPF in my desktop application.
In my XAML code , i have created a tab item with a listbox into it.
Now, in my xaml.cs file, on button click iam adding 1 tab .
What I wanted to do is, On button click, newly created tab should have listbox with other data.
So, how do i maintain a similar template for all tabs which are created ?
I know there are ways to create a similar style template for all tabitems. But i dont want to maintain same styles, but maintain same controls to whom i'll give datasource dynamically.

Here is my code xaml code:

```
                        <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueStyle" >
                            <TextBlock ToolTip="{Binding Path=Value}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" Padding="2" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                        </DataTemplate>

                        <Style x:Key="ExpandCollapseToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Border Width="16" Height="16" Background="Transparent" Padding="5,5,5,5">
                                        <Path x:Name="ExpandPath" Fill="Transparent" Stroke="#FF989898" Data="M0,0 L0,6 L6,0 z">
                                            <Path.RenderTransform>
                                                <RotateTransform Angle="135" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                                            </Path.RenderTransform>
                                        </Path>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF1BBBFA"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Fill" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </Trigger>

                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="RenderTransform">
                                                <Setter.Value>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="180" CenterX="3" CenterY="3"/>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Fill" Value="#FF595959"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="ExpandPath" Property="Stroke" Value="#FF262626"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.Resources>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                    <DataTemplate>

                      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MouseLeftButtonDown="ListItemClicked">
                         <Border Width="{Binding Path=Level, Converter={StaticResource ConvertLevelToIndent}}" />
                         <ToggleButton x:Name="tb" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=r1}" Width="100" />

                                <TextBlock FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Path=r2}" Width="100" />


                        </StackPanel>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=SubKeyCount}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="tb" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Comment: I have already bounded the data to class variables r1 and r2. What kind of binding are you saying  ? can u please explain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you need to repeat the same part of a UI, you can just put that part (the UI elements) into a `UserControl`... that's exactly what they're for. Once you add your UI controls to the XAML, then you can add `DependencyProperty`s that will enable you to `Bind` data from outside the `UserControl` to be displayed and/or edited inside the control. Here's a simple example:

In `UserControl` code behind:

```
public static DependencyProperty YourCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "YourCollection", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(YourUserControl));

public ObservableCollection<string> YourCollection
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(YourCollectionProperty); }
    set { SetValue(YourCollectionProperty, value); }
}
```

In `UserControl` XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type YourUserControl}}}" />
```

Then using your `UserControl`:

```
<YourXamlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl YourCollection="{Binding SomeCollection}" />
```

And in another place:

```
<YourXamlNamespacePrefix:YourUserControl YourCollection="{Binding OtherCollection}" />
```

Comment: I created an User control with grid into it. Now i want to use that user control as a tabitem whenever i click on a button. how can this be done ?

Comment: I showed you how to use your `UserControl` in my example... just add that line into a `TabItem.Content` section.